# Can I add class as extension to another class in Kotlin?

Tags: class, kotlin

For example, I know that I can add extension to class String like this:

```
val String.isValidEmail : Boolean
    get() {
        val expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$"
        val pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        val matcher = pattern.matcher(this)
        return matcher.matches()
    }
```

Now I want to add a *class as extension* into another class, which I think the implementation will be like this:

```
class Networking {
    ....
}

class Networking.Email {
    ....
}

// MainActivity.kt

val email = Networking.Email()
```

But this gave me error for "Networking.Email". For the "Networking" part: *Redeclaration: Networking*. For the "Email" part: *Expecting a top level declaration*. Is this actually possible in Kotlin?

Comment: what would be the benefit of such a class?

Comment: If you tell us what you want to achieve, there might be a workaround, but I think it would be a good idea to post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no such things as extension classes in Kotlin. See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html):

> Kotlin, similar to C# and Gosu, provides the ability to extend a class
>   with new functionality without having to inherit from the class or use
>   any type of design pattern such as Decorator. This is done via special
>   declarations called extensions. Kotlin supports extension functions
>   and extension properties.